# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE"

Tags: plsql

Estoy intentando crear un procedimiento almacenado pero me da el siguiente error:

> Error(17,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE"

Les dejo el código (corregido):

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_ingresar_cliente AS
    CURSOR cur_id_cli IS
            SELECT id_cliente FROM registro_cliente ORDER BY id_cliente DESC;
    PROCEDURE prc_ingreso_clientes (
    rut_cliente             IN registro_cliente.rut_cliente%TYPE,
    nombre_cliente          IN registro_cliente.nombre_cliente%TYPE,
    telefono_cliente        IN registro_cliente.telefono_cliente%TYPE,
    correo_cliente          IN registro_cliente.correo_cliente%TYPE,
    direccion_cliente       IN registro_cliente.direccion_cliente%TYPE,
    ifEmpresa               IN registro_cliente.ifEmpresa%TYPE,
    sexo_cliente            IN registro_cliente.sexo_cliente%TYPE,
    perfil_id_perfil        IN registro_cliente.perfil_id_perfil%TYPE,
    tarjeta_id_tarjeta      IN registro_cliente.tarjeta_id_tarjeta%TYPE,
    sucursal_id_sucursal    IN registro_cliente.sucursal_id_sucursal%TYPE);
    END pkg_ingresar_cliente;
    
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_ingresar_cliente AS
    PROCEDURE prc_ingreso_clientes (
    rut_cliente             IN registro_cliente.rut_cliente%TYPE,
    nombre_cliente          IN registro_cliente.nombre_cliente%TYPE,
    telefono_cliente        IN registro_cliente.telefono_cliente%TYPE,
    correo_cliente          IN registro_cliente.correo_cliente%TYPE,
    direccion_cliente       IN registro_cliente.direccion_cliente%TYPE,
    ifEmpresa               IN registro_cliente.ifEmpresa%TYPE,
    sexo_cliente            IN registro_cliente.sexo_cliente%TYPE,
    perfil_id_perfil        IN registro_cliente.perfil_id_perfil%TYPE,
    tarjeta_id_tarjeta      IN registro_cliente.tarjeta_id_tarjeta%TYPE,
    sucursal_id_sucursal    IN registro_cliente.sucursal_id_sucursal%TYPE)
    IS
    BEGIN
    FOR i IN cur_id_cli
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO registro_cliente VALUES (id_cliente_seq.NEXTVAL,rut_cliente,nombre_cliente,telefono_cliente,
correo_cliente,direccion_cliente,ifEmpresa,
        sexo_cliente,perfil_id_perfil,tarjeta_id_tarjeta,sucursal_id_sucursal);
    END LOOP;
    END prc_ingreso_clientes;
    END pkg_ingresar_cliente;
```

Comment: En mi caso yo ejecute la creación por separado, primero la cabecera y luego el cuerpo y creo el pkg sin errores de compilación. Gracias @gynch

Answer (score 1):

Te parecerá una tontería. Pero a mí ese error me ha pasado muchas veces cuando lanzo un script como el tuyo, que consta de dos: la cabecera del paquete y el cuerpo del paquete.

Muchos editores al ejecutarlo así consideran que es el mismo script y falla el segundo CREATE.

Lo que solemos hacer para evitar ésto es meter una barra (/) entre la cabecera y el cuerpo, de modo que lo toma como dos scripts diferentes, es decir:

```sql
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_ingresar_cliente AS
        CURSOR cur_id_cli IS
                SELECT id_cliente FROM registro_cliente ORDER BY id_cliente DESC;
        PROCEDURE prc_ingreso_clientes (
        rut_cliente             IN registro_cliente.rut_cliente%TYPE,
        nombre_cliente          IN registro_cliente.nombre_cliente%TYPE,
        telefono_cliente        IN registro_cliente.telefono_cliente%TYPE,
        correo_cliente          IN registro_cliente.correo_cliente%TYPE,
        direccion_cliente       IN registro_cliente.direccion_cliente%TYPE,
        ifEmpresa               IN registro_cliente.ifEmpresa%TYPE,
        sexo_cliente            IN registro_cliente.sexo_cliente%TYPE,
        perfil_id_perfil        IN registro_cliente.perfil_id_perfil%TYPE,
        tarjeta_id_tarjeta      IN registro_cliente.tarjeta_id_tarjeta%TYPE,
        sucursal_id_sucursal    IN registro_cliente.sucursal_id_sucursal%TYPE);
        END pkg_ingresar_cliente;
       
        /      

        CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_ingresar_cliente AS
        PROCEDURE prc_ingreso_clientes (
        rut_cliente             IN registro_cliente.rut_cliente%TYPE,
        nombre_cliente          IN registro_cliente.nombre_cliente%TYPE,
        telefono_cliente        IN registro_cliente.telefono_cliente%TYPE,
        correo_cliente          IN registro_cliente.correo_cliente%TYPE,
        direccion_cliente       IN registro_cliente.direccion_cliente%TYPE,
        ifEmpresa               IN registro_cliente.ifEmpresa%TYPE,
        sexo_cliente            IN registro_cliente.sexo_cliente%TYPE,
        perfil_id_perfil        IN registro_cliente.perfil_id_perfil%TYPE,
        tarjeta_id_tarjeta      IN registro_cliente.tarjeta_id_tarjeta%TYPE,
        sucursal_id_sucursal    IN registro_cliente.sucursal_id_sucursal%TYPE)
        IS
        BEGIN
        FOR i IN cur_id_cli
        LOOP
            INSERT INTO registro_cliente VALUES (id_cliente_seq.NEXTVAL,rut_cliente,nombre_cliente,telefono_cliente,
    correo_cliente,direccion_cliente,ifEmpresa,
            sexo_cliente,perfil_id_perfil,tarjeta_id_tarjeta,sucursal_id_sucursal);
        END LOOP;
        END prc_ingreso_clientes;
        END pkg_ingresar_cliente;
```

Comment: En efecto. Hay que ejecutar la instrucción anterior para que el cuerpo compile sin errores. Y para eso, uno usa el `/`, indicando que es hora de ejecutar las instrucciones que están en el buffer antes de seguir con el script.